# Write to rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, development-environment, rails-console

When I want to try or debug smthing I run `rails console` and do some stuff there. I can print some text or variables from code by raising exception with `raise "blablabla"`.
**Question:** How I can just write to *rails console* without exception raising (and obvious breaking code execution) like a simple `logger.info "blah"`?

Comment: puts "blah" ? this should work ;]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

As other have said, you want to use either `puts` or `p`. Why? Is that magic?

Actually not.  A rails console is, under the hood, an [IRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell), so all you can do in IRB you will be able to do in a rails console. Since for printing in an IRB we use `puts`, we use the same command for printing in a rails console.

You can actually take a look at the console [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/tools/console) in the rails source code. See the require of irb? :)

Answer (score 53):

[`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) or [`p`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p) is a good start to do that.

```
p "asd"       # => "asd"
puts "asd"    # => asd
```

here is more information about that: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html

Answer (score 12):

I think you should use the Rails debug options:

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
logger.info "Processing the request..."
logger.fatal "Terminating application, raised unrecoverable error!!!"
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 8):

In addition to already suggested `p` and `puts` — well, actually in most cases you do can write `logger.info "blah"` just as you suggested yourself. It works in console too, not only in server mode.

But if all you want is console debugging, `puts` and `p` are much shorter to write, anyway.