# Rails & Pow - how do I print something to stdout when my server script is being executed in dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-pow

So in python/django I can just put the line `print 'something'` in my code and `something` will get printed to the console.  How do I do this in Rails?  I'm on Mac using Pow as my development server.

Comment: Downvote for lack of research effort. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961691/write-to-rails-console. You can use [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

Comment: Why would I put in research effort when I can just ask on StackOverflow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, the downvote is explicitly for lack of research (mouseover the down arrow).

Comment: **Why would I put in research effort when I can just ask on StackOverflow?** laziest comment ever. Amazingly, and I know this might be hard to believe but most programming languages have a `print` method. I know crazy right?

Comment: Yeah, I know there is a print method - the question is how I can view the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pow stores log files for your apps in `~/Library/Logs/Pow/apps`.  You can `cd` to this directory in your terminal and then run `tail -f my_app.log` to view your log as it updates (`-f` is for 'follow').  You can then print from your ruby/rails scripts using the `puts` command and the output will appear in this log file.